# Online tool to convert photos into youtube video slideshow

Tags: video, youtube, photo

I'm looking for a free online tool that would allow creating photo slideshows and uploading them to youtube.

Animoto.com is a good example but only has a 30sec free option.

Answer (score 2):

Try [One True Media](http://www.onetruemedia.com/), you can [find more here](https://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&q=photo+video+slideshow+free&oq=photo+video+slideshow+free&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v3&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i15l3.2444.10872.0.11167.22.13.0.9.9.0.181.1148.10j3.13.0...0.0.uQWjur8tZHU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=758938a6fb1e532a&biw=1920&bih=912)

Comment: thx. That's similar to Animoto with only 30 seconds and low quality free, then you have to pay.

Comment: @MotoTribe there are quite a few out there - any video editing software should be able to do the job.

Comment: yes, but I'm looking for an online website rather than installed software.